pac4j implicit flow with silent authentication mechanism
I am planning to use SPA React application in the front end and to have my own authorization server (Spring boot with pac4j) and connect to idp to authenticate Single sign on( retrieve id token only with minimal information). Aftewards, retrive user account from my DB (Roles and permissions related to the user) to generate JWT (access token without refresh token) then send it to SPA in order to use it between microservices (all microservices are Spring boot apps). As per my understanding, for SPA, it is ok to use implicit frow of openID connect to authenticate with idp and also when my JWT expires go silently back to my authorization service to renew my access token withot user interaction (not sign in again). So, far I am able to retrive id token from idp and generate my own JWT. However, my doubt is how to implement silent mechanism so I can renew my JWT silently without sign in again.
It there any proper way that pac4j can help on this flow?
This is my  oidc configuration:
    @Bean
    public Config config() {
    final OidcConfiguration oidcConfiguration = new OidcConfiguration();
    oidcConfiguration.setClientId(pac4jProperties.getKeycloak().getClientId());
    oidcConfiguration.setSecret(pac4jProperties.getKeycloak().getSecret());
    oidcConfiguration.setUseNonce(true);
    oidcConfiguration.setDiscoveryURI(pac4jProperties.getKeycloak().getDiscoveryUri());
    oidcConfiguration.setScope(pac4jProperties.getKeycloak().getScope());
     oidcConfiguration.setClientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC);
    oidcConfiguration.addCustomParam("prompt", "consent");
    oidcConfiguration.setResponseType("id_token");
    oidcConfiguration.setResponseMode("form_post");
    final OidcClient oidcClient = new OidcClient(oidcConfiguration);
    oidcClient.setName(pac4jProperties.getKeycloak().getClientId());
    oidcClient.setCallbackUrl("http://localhost:8080/callback");
    oidcClient.setProfileCreator(new     CustomProfileCreator(userService,oidcClient.getConfiguration(),oidcClient));

        final Clients clients = new Clients("http://localhost:8080/callback", oidcClient);
    
        return new Config(clients);}


This should be the default behavior of pac4j: when you try to access a protected URL, the profile is retrieved from the session store (web session) and if no profile is available OR if the profile is expired, a login process is performed.
For the OIDC protocol, profiles expire when the access token is expired: https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/pac4j-parent-5.7.3/pac4j-oidc/src/main/java/org/pac4j/oidc/profile/OidcProfile.java#L191

Thanks Jerome for the response. If I only retrieve the id-token (for implicit flow), will this work with the id-token as well? I see it has an expiry time as well.

Another question, when renew of token is required after JWT expires, how this renewal must happen.  Must this happen via the Authorization server where it should go back to idp to renew id_token (silently without signing in again) and then back to the Authorization server to regenerate JWT, OR My browser must talk to idp directly (with iFrame) to reissue new id_token from idp then handle it to Authorization server.
If it must be with Browser, it there any pac4j library for the React/JS app to run iFrame for idp connection for id_token renewal? Can clarify this flow please?

Only the access token is take into account for the expiration of the OidcProfile but this can be customized.

The renew of the token should happen the same as the original login process itself.

No, it is not OK to use implicit flow and also, sending JWTs to a single-page or mobile application is not recommended anymore (skip to Final Recommendation if you do not have time to read the all post from Spring Security team).
I suggest you have a look at this article I wrote for Baeldung. It explains a way to implement an OAuth2 BFF (which is the recommended pattern in the Final Recommendation from the preceding linked post) with Spring Cloud Gateway and contains a sample UI written with React (Next.js).
